# Push notification not getting on mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I m using cordova 8.0 now.  Beforei was using6.5 . when I m using 6.5 i m getting push notification properly. Now i have updated cordova 8.0.0 after that i have installed firebase analystics and phonegap push plugin.

I have installed all plugins
updated google-services.json file,
updated config.xml file.
This is messenger related mobile app

After that test notification on firebase console i m getting.
but my app have messenger is there. If i m sending message to messenger i got in inside app. But push notification im not getting.

This issue on cordova 8 verison only. 
config.xml updated like this

```
     <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.1.3">
      <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="1:954650986639:android:135d209282da2c19" />
      <variable name="FCM_VERSION" value="11.6.2" />
    </plugin>
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
</platform>
```

Any one suggest me wantto update any other config!

Answer (score 0):

Google-services.json file gerenrate one project number. That number update your project senderID. It will work properly.